# Error in typing php info command flag

Tags: iis-7, command-line-interface, php-5.4

When I type:

> php -info

I get this error message:

> Could not open input file: o

I have php 5.4 installed. Trying to find info to configure IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was easy. Found the answer in an IIS forum.
http://forums.iis.net/t/1189386.aspx?Installing+PHP+on+IIS7

The -info flag has been depreciated. Its just -i now

Answer (score 0):

Try `php -i`.

`php -info` will be interpreted as `php -inf o` so cause that error.